# How to reject delete statement in before delete trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-delete

How to reject *delete* statement in **before delete trigger** (mysql) ?

Sample use case : I have a record with specified **id** that I want to will not be deleted.

Comment: what does that supposed to mean? Provide a use-case.

Comment: @Nishant : I added the sample use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a table that uses a foreign key constrait referencing your ID column (provided that is the primary key of your table). The insert a row into that "child" table that references ID = 0 and remove all update/delete privileges for your user from that table.

Now if someone tries to delete the row with ID = 0 in the "parent" table that will fail due to an existing child row in the other table.

Comment: this is very bad idea ( at least for me, because we have more than 130 table in our db)

Comment: @Behrouz: Does this mean you need this "protection" for every table? Sounds like a very strange setup then..

Comment: not for each tables, but I have a lot of relations between tables, and this solutions make it more complex. I wrote a ORM , that generates SOAP web services, adding an extra useless column, make out webservices ugly and error prone

Comment: You don't add an extra *column* (because the column **id** is already there) you add an extra *table* which can totally be ignored by your ORM as it only serves to purpose to prevent deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Look here, same thing but with an insert-trigger: [How to abort INSERT operation in MySql trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538786/how-to-abort-insert-operation-in-mysql-trigger)