# Prevent a record form being deleted or updated via the use of a Mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using Mysql and  trying to create a trigger on a table that prevents a specific record from being deleted or updated, example I have a table `demo`

```
id    username    password
1     dames       t312llok
2     sauce       12ff1fff1
3     hynes       5656166oo9
```

I would like to prevent the record:

```
id    username    password
1     dames       t312llok
```

from being deleted or updated via the use of a trigger

Comment: Your question is very general, what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132356/how-to-reject-delete-statement-in-before-delete-triger-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.5 or higher, this is simple.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS demo_bd $$
CREATE TRIGGER demo_bd BEFORE DELETE ON demo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.id = 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This magical user cannot be deleted';
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

For the update, it's exactly the same code, with minor tweaks.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS demo_bu $$
CREATE TRIGGER demo_bu BEFORE UPDATE ON demo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.id = 1 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This magical user cannot be updated';
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also... don't store passwords in the database.